# C# windows form manage multiple image visibility

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

[image]

I have a map of possible locations of a vehicle. I want to display an image like a black dot on the top of this one to show the position in each moment. The only way that I am seeing is to display one positioning image on the top of each possible placement on the map and then update one by one:

```
pic_position_r1.Visible = false;
pic_position_r2.Visible = false;
pic_position_r3.Visible = false;
...
pic_position_g1.Visible = false;
...
pic_position_b1.Visible = false;
...

switch (position)
    {
        case "R1": pic_position_r1.Visible = true; break;
        case "R2": pic_position_r2.Visible = true; break;
        ...
        case "G1": pic_position_g1.Visible = true; break;
        ...
        case "B1": pic_position_b1.Visible = true; break;
        ...

    }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the controls in an array and use enums for easy access.

```
public enum foo
{
  r1,
  g2
}

public void urMom()
{
  PictureBox[] obj = new PictureBox[]
  {
      pic_position_r1,
      pic_position_g2
  };

  foreach(PictureBox b in obj)
    b.Visible = false;

  obj[Convert.ToInt32(foo.g2)].Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Don´t understand the foo, is it like a vector?

Comment: Foo is of type enum. Enums are basically ints as strings to make things readable. It's good practice to use them.

Comment: I receive position as a string from sockets, is there a easier way to update the visibility of the picture elements? like if (b.text=="R1") b.visible=true else b.visible=false ?

Comment: In that scenario, you can simplify the code to b.visible = (b.text=="R1"); But if you can, try changing the code to use the enum I have in my example instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

> I receive position as a string from sockets, is there a easier way to
>   update the visibility of the picture elements? like if (b.text=="R1")
>   b.visible=true else b.visible=false ?

Simply **SEARCH** for your corresponding control using [Controls.Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
string position = "R1"; // string from your socket
string ctlName = "pic_position_" + position.ToLower(); // build up control name from the received string
Control match = this.Controls.Find(ctlName, true).FirstOrDefault(); // find the control
if (match != null) // see if a match was found
{
    match.Visible = true;
}
```